# How to watch DVDs in Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, dvd, 13.10

I have Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit and I am new to Ubuntu, I noticed if I put a DVD into my DVD drive it will not play. Is there something I can download that can let me watch DVDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to check if it is legal in your area. because in some places it is illeagal to watch DVDs in Linux.

open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), copy and paste the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg libxine1-ffmpeg gxine mencoder libdvdread4 totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 mpg321 && sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

you might also need VLC to watch some DVDs

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Why would it be illegal to watch DVD's in Linux?

Comment: Some legislations forbid to “circumvent” a (broken) DRM system with an open source library. You can still watch unencrypted, region-free DVDs in those countries though.

Comment: @seth because it is... http://www.itworld.com/open-source/105736/legalizing-linux-dvd-playback-why-bother